Conditions for convergence of gradient flow/descent with non-isolated critical points
I am trying to show the convergence of gradient flow for a function $f(x(t))$ where $\frac{d}{dt}(x(t)) = -\nabla_x(f(x))$ which will be some polynomial in $x(t)$. $f$ is the square of a 3rd degree polynomial of the parameters x and thus is always positive. Unfortunately I have little experience in dynamical systems and so was asking for some advice here.
I am just interested in showing that gradient flow converges at all as I can already show that if it converges, it will converge to the true global minima.  In this particular case there is a line of true minima, so none of these critical points are isolated and gradient flow may converge to any of them. If I could show that $x(t)$ was bounded(that is, it will remain bounded or not leave some positive invariant set) then we would know that $x(t)$ converges (Barbalat's lemma since $f''(x(t))$ will just be some polynomial).
$f(x(t))$ will be bounded since it converges but it is difficult to use this to show boundedness of $f''(x(t))$. The way f depends on the parameters is something of a form like $x_1(t)\times x_2(t)$ so $x_2(t)$ may be growing while $x_1(t)$ shrinks. I haven't found any other clear methods to show that $x(t)$ would be bounded other than showing that it converges. So, I was wondering if anyone had any suggested methods to show the boundedness of solutions to a dynamical system given some starting initialization.
I can also show that $x(t)$ must be arbitrarily close to one of these global minima for all times $t$. In this case we also know that there is some ball around each of these points for which the Hessian of $f$ is positive semidefinite(and thus the function is locally convex). But again it may leave this locally convex set and I haven't found any methods for showing some sort of region of attraction for global minima when initialized suitably close. Most methods I can find focus on convergence to a particular point, which would be impossible to show here as there can be no asymptotic stability of particular fixed points(since they're not isolated).  So, I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions on showing the local asymptotic convergence of a set of points.
Regarding other methods I have found:
Every Lyapunov method I have found in one way or another assumes that there is an isolated fixed point(in this case none of these minima will be isolated). The LaSalle invariance principle already assumes $x(t)$ is bounded. These Lyapunov methods are thus particularly difficult because depending on the initialization, $x(t)$ may converge to any one of these global minima(which is fine).
I have also found some previous results by Recht and Jordan which show gradient flow/descent will converge to a local minimizer(which would be what I want) assuming that the parameters are bounded or the critical point is isolated. Again the critical points aren't isolated and if I could show boundedness of the solution I would be done. This might follow trivially from something like the center manifold theorem but unfortunately my knowledge of manifolds and dynamical systems isn't quite developed enough to fully understand that.
Thank you for any help, I really appreciate it.

I think you need some conditions to ensure that a trajectory is bounded. If this is true, it is straightforward to show that $x$ has an $\omega$-limit that is an equilibrium.

Yeah, part of the question was conditions under which all trajectories would be bounded. In this case I can prove my result, however being able to establish to some region of attraction for a set of nonisolated points might also suffice.
